# Why is Google Play sign in "Confirm your choices" extra popup shown?

Tags: android, google-play, google-oauth, google-play-services, google-signin

Currently, I am implementing the Google Play sign in and it works fine functionally.

When I test the implementation, I realized that there is one extra popup with the title "Confirm your choices" after allowing the first popup.

I couldn't find any way to get rid of that second step neither with configurations in the code nor with the setup on the Google Play console.

[image: Confirm your choices popup]

Does anybody know the reason that Google Play sign in shows this "Confirm your choices" popup and how can I get rid of that extra step?

Here is the GoogleSignInOptions:

```
GoogleSignInOptions googleSignInOptions = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken("some-id)
            .build();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is intended behavior and not something you can get rid of, per the Google announcement of this feature in 2018 [1]. You can also find documentation about this in Google's policies for applications using Sign In With Google/OAuth, which includes Play [2].

[1] https://developers.googleblog.com/2018/10/more-granular-google-account.html

[2] https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/policies#unbundled-consent

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What I want to improve here is user experience. Currently, for Play login, 2 popups are shown. The 2nd one I shared in the question is almost same with the 1st one but only checkboxes are added. In this case, 1st one is pretty redundant.
I check some of the live games and they just require 1 popup to get the permissions. From the link you shared, I can consider them as old games which are released before 2018 so Google didn't roll out this approach for them yet.
However, do you think is there any way to get rid of this first popup to improve the user experience?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think there is an alternative at this time. You could consider inserting your own UI explaining to the users that they'll be seeing a multi consent step before you redirect them to sign in. You could also encourage your users to enable this feature that would then reduce friction: https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/sign-in#automatic-sign-in

Comment: Thank you for your helps, it is already a lot. Last one thing:
in the link you shared, there is a gif related with manual sign-in (https://developers.google.com/games/services/images/manual-sign-in.gif), this is the exact behaviour that I want to achieve. However, in my case, there are 2 popups shown even if I don't request the id token. Is that an outdated gif? If not, how can I have the same behaviour? Also, there are live games with the same behaviour with that gif, how that can happen?